# php : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, foreach

I just can't figure it out.. but i got a feeling the problem is around there when im throwing the exception messages. I got almost the same code in my registration class. There is just give the errors array the messages normaly like $this->errors[] = "some error".

```
<?php


class class_login 
{
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $passmd5;

    private $errors;
    private $access;
    private $login;
    private $ltoken;

    public function __cunstruct()
    {
        $this->errors = array();

        $this->login  = isset($_POST['login'])? 1:0;
        $this->access = 0;
        $this->ltoken  = $_POST['ltoken'];
        $this->id     = 0;
        $this->username = ($this->login)? $this->filter($_POST['lusername']) : $_SESSION['username'];
        $this->password = ($this->login)? $this->filter($_POST['lpassword']) : '';
        $this->passmd5 = ($this->login)? md5($this->password) : $_SESSION['password'];

    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        ($this->login)? $this->verifyPost() : $this->verifySession();

        return $this->access;
    }

    public function filter($var)
    {
        return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','',$var);
    }

    public function verifyPost()
    {
        try
        {
            if(!$this->tokenValid())
                throw new Exception('Invalid Form Submission!');
            if(!$this->isDataValid())
                throw new Exception('Ivalid Form Data!');
            if(!$this->verifyDatabase())
                throw new Exception('Invalid Username/Password!');

            $this->access = 1;
            $this->registerSession();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $this->errors[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function verifySession()
    {
        if($this->sessionExist() && $this->verifyDatabase())
        $this->access = 1;
    }

    public function verifyDatabase()
    {
        include('db_connect.php');

        $data = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = '($this->username)' AND password = '($this->passmd5)'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($data))
        {
            list($this->id) = @array_values(mysql_fetch_assoc($data));

            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

       }

    public function isDataValid()
    {
        return (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9](5,12)$/',  $this->username) && preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9](5,12)$/',  $this->password))? 1:0;
    }

    public function tokenValid()
    {
        return (!isset($_SESSION['ltoken']) || $this->ltoken != $_SESSION['ltoken'])? 0 : 1;
    }

    public function registerSession()
    {
        $_SESSION['ID']       = $this->id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $this->username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $this->passmd5;
    }

    public function sessionExist()
    {
        return (isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))? 1 : 0;
    }

    public function show_errors()
    {
        foreach($this->errors as $key=>$value)
            echo $value."</br>";
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: It should be ->construct not  __cunstruct(), if its correct what PHP version you are using?

Comment: it is __cunstruct(), thats not the problem. Using 5.3.8. Thx.

Comment: nvm i see what you mean, thank you

Comment: where you saw it is `__cunstruct`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is called `__construct`, not `__cunstruct`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are setting $this->errors to an array in your **__cunstruct** function, but since it is not __construct it may never be set.

Answer (score 0):

You need a associative array for

```
foreach($this->errors as $key=>$value)
```

But you have no one. ($this->errors[] = $e->getMessage();)

With out an associative array you must use:

```
foreach($this->errors as $value)
```

Comment: You can still use $key => $value with a non-associative array (in PHP all arrays are really associative).  $key will just be the implicit index instead of an explicit key.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function __cunstruct() <------ The error is probably here. It is __construct
    {
        $this->errors = array();

        $this->login  = isset($_POST['login'])? 1:0;
        $this->access = 0;
        $this->ltoken  = $_POST['ltoken'];
        $this->id     = 0;
        $this->username = ($this->login)? $this->filter($_POST['lusername']) : $_SESSION['username'];
        $this->password = ($this->login)? $this->filter($_POST['lpassword']) : '';
        $this->passmd5 = ($this->login)? md5($this->password) : $_SESSION['password'];

    }
```

You have a typo.... **_*construct*** and not **_construct**